# Prototype with Boostrap 3.3.4 popover bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, prototype, popover

When using both prototype and bootstrap 3.3.4, there is a glitch where a popovers' parent element is hidden along with the popover when the hide.bs.* event is called. After several days of searching for a solution to this old issue and coming across nothing but outdated answers that are no longer valid for the most recent bootstrap release, I've finally decided to ask if anyone has a solution to this issue.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please post a question and an answer separately.

Comment: Thank you, I'll post my answer separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Open bootstrap.js**

**Step 2: Find the "Tooltip.prototype.hide" function**

**Step 3: Replace the following line of code:**

```
this.$element.trigger(e)
```

**with this**

```
if( this.type != 'popover') {
    this.$element.trigger(e)
}
```

And that's it.

If anyone has a better solution to this issue, please let me know. I'd rather not alter the core js file if I don't have to.